# Plotting multiple series in single Highcharts plot from JSON

Tags: javascript, json, plot, highcharts

So I have a JSON object that I am trying to plot using `Highcharts`. The JSON object looks similar to the following:

```
json_data = [
    {
        'name': "col1",
        'data': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]},
    {
        'name': "col2",
        'data': [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]},
    {
        'name': "col3",
        'data': [2, 3, 4, 5, 6]},
    {
        'name': "col4",
        'data': [-1, -2, -3, -4, -5]},
]
```

I can plot it via `Highcharts` with the following code:

```
$('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'line',
        },
        legend: {
               layout: 'vertical',
               align: 'right',
               verticalAlign: 'middle',
               borderWidth: 0,
        },
        title: {
                text: 'Data',
                x: -20 // center title
        },
        xAxis: {
              title: {text: 'Velocity (m/sec)'},            
        },
        yAxis: {title: {text: 'Force (N)'}},
        series: json_data,
    });
```

This plots all 4 columns within my `json_data`, but what I am trying to do is to plot `col2` against `col1` and `col4` against `col3` on the same chart so there will only be 2 line plots in the chart. In other words the x-axis will be defined by both `col1` and `col3` and the two line plots will have different intervals(x-ticks). I know I can define different `series` within the `series:` parameter, but I am struggling to understand how I can select these from within my JSON object.

Essentially I need to rearrange my JSON from its original format into two series of data that look something like this:

```
// col2 against col1
series1 = [ [1, 2],
            [2, 4],
            [3, 6],
            [4, 8],
            [5, 10]
]

// col4 against col3
series2 = [ [2, -1],
            [3, -2],
            [4, -3],
            [5, -4],
            [6, -5]
]
```

Any help on how I could accomplish this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any posterity here is the solution I came up with which assumes that every data array is the same length (my use case):

```
    var arr = [json_data];

    // first series data to plot
    var series1 = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < arr[0][0].data.length; i++)
    {
        var temp = [];
        temp.push(arr[0][0].data[i]);
        temp.push(arr[0][1].data[i]);                   
        series1.push(temp);
    }

    // second series data to plot
    var series2 = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < arr[0][0].data.length; i++)
    {
        var temp = [];
        temp.push(arr[0][2].data[i]);
        temp.push(arr[0][3].data[i]);                   
        series2.push(temp);
    }
```

And within my `highcharts series:` parameter:

```
     series: [{
            name: "Series 1",
            data: series1
     }, {
            name: "Series 2",
            data: series2
     }],
```